# Java 8 Functional Interface Default and Static methods Return Type same as Functional Interface name?

Tags: java

In java 8 Functional Interface why the default and static methods should have a return type as Same Functional Interface name.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {

    public int compare(T t1, T t2);

    public default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> cmp){
        return (p1,p2)->compare(p1,p2)==0?cmp.compare(p1, p2):compare(p1,p2);
    } // return an int

    public default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T,Comparable> f){
        return thenComparing(comparing(f)); // return an int
    }

    public static <U>Comparator<U> comparing(Function<U,Comparable> f){
        return (p1,p2)->f.apply(p1).compareTo(f.apply(p2)); // return an int
    }
}
```

Comment: Because that's the type they are *designed* to return. What other type do you think they should return, and why?

Answer (score 1):

They don't have to. Methods can be void or return whatever.

It just happens that `Comparator` has static and default methods that return `Comparator`, but this is just casual.

Many default methods return the self type because this allows for method chaining.

Answer (score 1):

The default static methods define as return type only what they need.

For `Comparator` it makes sense to return a  `Comparator` as these methods are factory methods.

Looks at other Functional Interfaces that have default static methods and  you will see different things.
For example : `Iterable.forEach()` is defined as `default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`

Answer (score 1):

Static/default methods in functional interfaces don't get special treatment. They work like any other default/static methods in an ordinary interface. They can return whatever they like.

You see the static/default methods in a functional interface return the same type a lot because it makes sense to put them there.

For example, where else would you put the `comparing` method? In `Consumer<T>` or `Supplier<T>`? No, it only makes sense to put it in `Comparator<T>`. For the `thenComparing` methods, it's because it's useful and very readable to just call them on a comparator object:

```
Comparator.comparing(x -> x.something).thenComparing(x -> x.somethingElse)
```

If you write your own functional interface and you think of some operation that can be done on it that transforms it into another functional interface, then add it in! Write a default method that returns another type!